# Contributing to Nextcloud - How to understand code structure?

Tags: php, vue.js, nextcloud

I would like to contribute to Nextcloud because there are some issues that are quite easily fixed but aren't by the developers.
Now this might sound like a stupid question, but I can't find ANY information on how the code is structured. There is no documentation I could find whatsoever.

I also can't find any information of other people developing with Nextcloud as issues on Github are not answered.

Is there any information available or is it only Open Source in the sense that all structure is kept private by Nextcloud GmbH and only the code is made public?

Specifically I am looking for information on which Vue.js component does what and where I would have to look to find the functions that are doing what I'm searching for.